# How to stopPropagation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, stoppropagation

I have looked all over and can't fully understand what I'm doing wrong.

I just want the parent element not to fire (change opacity) when clicking the child.

Simple answers are appreciated!

Thank you

```
HTML
<div id="not-clicker">
    <div id="clicker" onClick="clickBox();">
    </div>
</div>

JAVASCRIPT
function clickBox(event) {
    document.getElementById('clicker').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    event.stopPropagation();
};
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/killamilla/R8tHA/1/) (Doesn't work properly)

Comment: There are some errors in your fiddle: You are using getElementByTag and are loading the script at onload. Corrected example: http://jsfiddle.net/some/2kLzd/

Answer (score 1):

This will not capture the event. You will need an event handler to do that. As a result, you need to refactor to avoid using inline javascript

html change

```
<div id="clicker"></div>
```

js change

```
document.getElementById('clicker').onclick = function(event){
 document.getElementById('clicker').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
 //this.style.backgroundColor = 'green';note you can also use this to reference the element now
 event.stopPropagation();
};
```

*edit*

**Further information**

Note that since this is no longer being inlined, the script must run after the element is in the DOM. To do this, you will need to place the script lower in the page, or wait for the window's load event to fire. Here is an example of that

```
window.onload = function(){//this callback executes when the window is fully loaded
 //now we can guarantee all DOM elements are present
 document.getElementById('clicker').onclick = function(event){
  this.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  event.stopPropagation();
 };
};
```

Comment: Thanks Travis for explaining that code, but it is still not working properly.

When I click the red box the opacity changes signifying that the parent element is still firing. 

Maybe, I'm asking the wrong question.

Comment: @MikeMilla - I see what you are experiencing. It would seem that javascript has no control over limiting the `:active` css attribute by using `stopPropagation`.

Answer (score 0):

On your jsfiddle the `clickBox` is in onLoad.. use "No Wrap in head" on left side

And you have there `getElementByTag`! Use `getElementById`.